# Is there any way to set session timeout in seconds in web.xml by doing some tweaking?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a requirement to set the session timeout of 40 seconds. I know we keep normally to 20 minutes. But my current application requirement is to keep the session timeout in seconds that is to 40 seconds. The web.xml is taking only integer value as 1 but it is not taking 0.6. Is there any way to write this? We are running our java web application on Apache tomcat server.

The minimum value i am able to set in web.xml is 1 minute like:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I can set the session timeout to 40 seconds by using session.setMaxInactiveInterval(40); but the session.setMaxInactiveInterval(40); works only when the website is opened by the user. But as soon as the user closes the website session.setMaxInactiveInterval method will not work and the default web.xml takes control and again sets the session time out to 1 minute.

Is there any way to set session timeout in seconds in web.xml by doing some tweaking?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `web.xml` allows only for minutes. If you want to use seconds, you'd have to do it programatically by registering a custom `HttpSessionListener` (or similar) in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sample.SessionTimeoutSetter</listener-class>
</listener>
```

```
public class SessionTimeoutSetter implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(40);
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // not needed
    }
}
```

Taken from `servlet-api-2.4`'s `HttpSession`

```
/**
 * Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the
 * servlet container will invalidate this session.  A negative time
 * indicates the session should never timeout.
 *
 * @param interval An integer specifying the number of seconds
 */
public void setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval);
```

Comment: Then what value i have to write in place of 1
<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
in web.xml file

Comment: You can comment it out stating that it's being set by your class